# Caching Futures and using as they complete

Tags: java, multithreading, caching, collections, concurrency

I was wondering if there's a way to cache Futures to be able to use as they complete.  For example, I have a main thread that spawns off an executor that reads in from an input stream:

```
// pseudo code
while(true){
   Callable task = new Callable({
      // setup callable stuff here
      byte[] call(){
        return inputStream.readInBytes();
      }
   });
   Future f = executors.submit(task);
   byte[] b = f.get();  // blocks   Uggh

   // execute of b
   process(b);
}
```

I was wondering if there's a way to put the futures into a Collection and then process as they complete.

```
// pseudo code
while(true){
   Callable task = new Callable({
      // setup callable stuff here
      byte[] call(){
        return inputStream.readInBytes();
      }
   });
   Future f = executors.submit(task);

   futures.add(f);

   // process bytes as they completed.
   for(Future f: futures){
       if(f.isDone()){   // this doesn't always return valid.  It sometimes throws NPE's
         b = f.get();
         process (b);
       }
   }

}
```

I've tried the second code piece, but it will throw NPE's sometimes - I assume the 'isDone' method is being called on threads that are just starting up which is the problem (guessing).

Does anyone know of a way to cache the futures until they start completing?  Right now my program works serially, but I am looking for ways to optimize it and speed it up.

thanks

Comment: Removed my use of `Byte` and made them `byte`

Comment: Have a look at CompletableFuture() in Java8. This is not the easiest technique to implement

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `Byte[]` instead I would use `byte[]` or a recycle able buffer.

If you want to process the data as it becomes available, do it in the back ground thread.

```
/* loop */ {
   futures.add(new Callable<Result>() {
      // setup callable stuff here
      Result call(){
           byte[] bytes = inputStream.readInBytes();
           return process(bytes);
      }
   });
}

// collect the results
for(Future<Result> f: futures){
    Result result = g.get();
    // do something single thread
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Result result = g.get();` block, preventing the for loop from advancing?  Also how do we know that `result` has completed?

Comment: I just implemented your code and it runs in serial time.  There's no parallel processing happening.

Comment: @Dan did you move the get() *outside* the loop?  If there is nothing to do after the process() you might not need the `futures` list at all.

Comment: If you need to keep reading until there is no more data, you should place this inside the Callable, not outside it.